# How to not loose undo/redo stack data on updating column definition in AG-Grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-vue

I am working on an Ag-grid project, where I have a toggle button to toggle between two groupBy's. Each group by has different Column definitions, which I am then updating using GridApi.  When the updation of column definitions happens, the undo/redo stack is lost. Is there a way to retain those or any alternate solutions.

I tried looking for it in the doc, but I couldn't find anything related to it.

Comment: Have you tried toggling between two grids?